# html tags disappears when I put a PHP code

Tags: php, html-table

It's a mystery to me. I have a Html block of codes here, and I want records to loop using table with PHP. Now, when I add a PHP code, everything that is below PHP is all gone, even in the view source code. I wonder what is happening. When I put PHP in the bottom, everything shows, when I put PHP in the middle, just the above html shows up in the view source.

```
<?php include('incl/connect.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style2.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tables.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <style>
    .content{
        height: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .content div {
        position: relative;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="tabs">
            <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label-1">Home</label>

            <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-2" />
            <label for="tab-2" class="tab-label-2">Repairs</label>

            <input id="tab-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-3" />
            <label for="tab-3" class="tab-label-3">yet</label>

            <input id="tab-4" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-4" />
            <label for="tab-4" class="tab-label-4">yet</label>

            <div class="clear-shadow"></div>

            <div class="content">
                <div class="content-1">
                    <p>Search <input type="search" placeholder="Search"></p>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">All
                    <input type="checkbox" >Female only
                    <input type="checkbox" >Male only
                    <table cellspacing='0'> <!-- cellspacing='0' is important, must stay -->
                        <!-- Table Header -->
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Fullname</th>
                                <th>Status?</th>
                                <th>Remaining time</th>
                                <th>Expires</th>
                                <th>Active</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <!-- Table Header -->

                        <!-- Table Body -->
                        <tbody>
                            <?php $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM client"); 
$member = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $member['nick']; ?></td>
                                <td>here </td>
                                <td></td>

                            </tr><!-- Table Row -->

                        </tbody>
                        <!-- Table Body -->

                    </table>
                </div><!--- content-1 end -->
                <div class="content-2">
                   <h2>Repairs</h2>

                </div><!-- content- end-->
                <div class="content-3">
                    <h2>soon</h2>
                    <p></p>
                </div><!--content-3 end-->
                <div class="content-4">
                    <h2>sooon</h2>
                    <p></p>
                </div><!--- content-4 end -->
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no source code, could you provide it?

Comment: Please show the appropriate HTML/PHP code. We're not able to help without anything shown.

Comment: ! how can i paste the whole code. ^_^

Comment: @yul757 There is an `edit` link below your question.

Comment: there is my code. posting codes here very difficult! ^_^ thanks friends.

Comment: My first guess is wrong, all PHP tags are closed. Which of the PHP code parts have you moved to the bottom?

Comment: ^_^ all of it. part of it. still not working. I cant really figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I see two error possibilites

- [PDO::query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) returns `false` on failure, but you don't test the return value. If `$query` is false, the `fetch` part will fail with an error message and stop the script.
- Another one could be, that you don't have a column named `nick`

Comment: That was my first thought, too :)

Comment: I only have 3 lines of php code here, I wast just testing for a while loop, but not using while loop yet.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. ^_^ its my php connect.  I forgot I was in a different location. thanks. I will note this error.  Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using PHP inside HTML:

```
<table style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($this->masters as $val) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="64px" style="padding: 1px;">

                    <img style="margin-left: 20px;" alt="" src="<?php echo $this->url; ?>img/palm_tree_purple.png"></img>

                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <h5 style="margin: 1px;"><?php echo $val; ?></h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When you want to use PHP, you open with the PHP tag `<?php`, then when you are finished using PHP you close it with `?>`. You can then continue to use HTML.